# Suddenly Getting "Duplicate Identifier" Errors in My Angular2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, hammer.js

I've been working on an Angular 2 app, and have made steady progress. Then, all of sudden, half way through the day today I got an error when trying to boot up the app. I haven't been working on anything relevant to the errors I'm getting, so I'm not sure why I'm getting these errors now. The errors have to do with hammerjs, inside of my node_modules folder. Here are some of the errors:

```
typings/globals/hammerjs/index.d.ts(90,11): error TS2430: Interface 'HammerOptions' incorrectly extends interface 'HammerDefaults'.
  Property 'domEvents' is optional in type 'HammerOptions' but required in type 'HammerDefaults'.
typings/globals/hammerjs/index.d.ts(116,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'HammerInput'.
typings/globals/hammerjs/index.d.ts(194,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MouseInput'.
typings/globals/hammerjs/index.d.ts(199,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PointerEventInput'.
typings/globals/hammerjs/index.d.ts(204,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'SingleTouchInput'.
typings/globals/hammerjs/index.d.ts(209,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TouchInput'.
typings/globals/hammerjs/index.d.ts(214,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TouchMouseInput'.
typings/globals/hammerjs/index.d.ts(313,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TouchAction'.
```

This is strange, because when I open up those files, I don't visibly see any of those identifiers being duplicated, so I'm not sure why I'm getting these particular errors?

Here is my npm-debug log:

```
 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.8.0/bin/node',
    1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
    1 verbose cli   'start' ]
    2 info using npm@3.10.8
    3 info using node@v6.8.0
    4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
    5 info lifecycle abc@0.0.1~prestart: abc@0.0.1
    6 silly lifecycle abc@0.0.1~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
    7 info lifecycle abc@0.0.1~start: abc@0.0.1
    8 verbose lifecycle abc@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    9 verbose lifecycle abc@0.0.1~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/ef/Documents/quin-backup/abc/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.8.0/bin:/Users/ef/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/Users/ef/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/bin:/Users/ef/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/ef/.rvm/bin:/Users/ef/.rvm/bin
    10 verbose lifecycle ARK@0.0.1~start: CWD: /Users/ef/Documents/quin-backup/abc
    11 silly lifecycle abc@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '-c', 'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" ' ]
    12 silly lifecycle abc@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
    13 info lifecycle abc@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
    14 verbose stack Error: abc@0.0.1 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
    14 verbose stack Exit status 2
    14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:255:16)
    14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
    14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
    15 verbose pkgid ARK@0.0.1
    16 verbose cwd /Users/ef/Documents/backup/abc
    17 error Darwin 15.6.0
    18 error argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.8.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
    19 error node v6.8.0
    20 error npm  v3.10.8
    21 error code ELIFECYCLE
    22 error ARK@0.0.1 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
    22 error Exit status 2
    23 error Failed at the abc@0.0.1 start script 'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
    23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the abc package,
    23 error not with npm itself.
    23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    23 error     tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"
    23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    23 error     npm bugs abc
    23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    23 error     npm owner ls abc
    23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
    24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've also tried removing my node_modules folder and running npm install again, but I run into the same problem.

And again, this is a problem that just arose today. No issues before now.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "docs": "typedoc --experimentalDecorators --out docs/ app/ --target 'es5' -module 'system' --ignoreCompilerErrors",
    "clean": "del /q dist",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10",
    "minify": "uglifyjs dist/main.min.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --output dist/main.min.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && tsc",
    "build_prod": "npm run build && browserify -s main dist/main.js > dist/main.min.js && npm run minify"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0",
    "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@angular2-material/input": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.4.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.32",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10"
  }
}
```

The errors trace back to this file (in which I can't identify any problems):

```
// Type definitions for Hammer.js 2.0.8
// Project: http://hammerjs.github.io/
// Definitions by: Philip Bulley <https://github.com/milkisevil/>, Han Lin Yap <https://github.com/codler>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

declare var Hammer:HammerStatic;

declare module "hammerjs" {
    export = Hammer;
}

interface HammerStatic
{
  new( element:HTMLElement | SVGElement, options?:HammerOptions ): HammerManager;

  defaults:HammerDefaults;

  VERSION: number;

  INPUT_START:  number;
  INPUT_MOVE:   number;
  INPUT_END:    number;
  INPUT_CANCEL: number;

  STATE_POSSIBLE:   number;
  STATE_BEGAN:      number;
  STATE_CHANGED:    number;
  STATE_ENDED:      number;
  STATE_RECOGNIZED: number;
  STATE_CANCELLED:  number;
  STATE_FAILED:     number;

  DIRECTION_NONE:       number;
  DIRECTION_LEFT:       number;
  DIRECTION_RIGHT:      number;
  DIRECTION_UP:         number;
  DIRECTION_DOWN:       number;
  DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL: number;
  DIRECTION_VERTICAL:   number;
  DIRECTION_ALL:        number;

  Manager:     HammerManagerConstructor;
  Input:       HammerInput;
  TouchAction: TouchAction;

  TouchInput:        TouchInput;
  MouseInput:        MouseInput;
  PointerEventInput: PointerEventInput;
  TouchMouseInput:   TouchMouseInput;
  SingleTouchInput:  SingleTouchInput;

  Recognizer:     RecognizerStatic;
  AttrRecognizer: AttrRecognizerStatic;
  Tap:            TapRecognizerStatic;
  Pan:            PanRecognizerStatic;
  Swipe:          SwipeRecognizerStatic;
  Pinch:          PinchRecognizerStatic;
  Rotate:         RotateRecognizerStatic;
  Press:          PressRecognizerStatic;

  on( target:EventTarget, types:string, handler:Function ):void;
  off( target:EventTarget, types:string, handler:Function ):void;
  each( obj:any, iterator:Function, context:any ):     void;
  merge( dest:any, src:any ):    any;
  extend( dest:any, src:any, merge:boolean ):   any;
  inherit( child:Function, base:Function, properties:any ):any;
  bindFn( fn:Function, context:any ):Function;
  prefixed( obj:any, property:string ):string;
}

type RecognizerTuple =
  [RecognizerStatic]
  | [RecognizerStatic, RecognizerOptions]
  | [RecognizerStatic, RecognizerOptions, string | string[]]
  | [RecognizerStatic, RecognizerOptions, string | string[], (string | Recognizer) | (string | Recognizer)[]];

interface HammerDefaults extends HammerOptions
{
  domEvents:boolean;
  enable:boolean;
  preset:RecognizerTuple[];
  touchAction:string;
  cssProps:CssProps;

  inputClass:() => void;
  inputTarget:EventTarget;
}

interface CssProps
{
  contentZooming:string;
  tapHighlightColor:string;
  touchCallout:string;
  touchSelect:string;
  userDrag:string;
  userSelect:string;
}

interface HammerOptions
{
  cssProps?:CssProps;
  domEvents?:boolean;
  enable?:boolean | ((manager: HammerManager) => boolean);
  preset?:RecognizerTuple[];
  touchAction?:string;
  recognizers?:RecognizerTuple[];

  inputClass?:() => void;
  inputTarget?:EventTarget;
}

interface HammerManagerConstructor {
  new( element:EventTarget, options?:HammerOptions ):HammerManager;
}

interface HammerListener {
  (event:HammerInput): void
}

interface HammerManager
{
  add( recogniser:Recognizer ):Recognizer;
  add( recogniser:Recognizer ):HammerManager;
  add( recogniser:Recognizer[] ):Recognizer;
  add( recogniser:Recognizer[] ):HammerManager;
  destroy():void;
  emit( event:string, data:any ):void;
  get( recogniser:Recognizer ):Recognizer;
  get( recogniser:string ):Recognizer;
  off( events:string, handler?:HammerListener ):void;
  on( events:string, handler:HammerListener ):void;
  recognize( inputData:any ):void;
  remove( recogniser:Recognizer ):HammerManager;
  remove( recogniser:string ):HammerManager;
  set( options:HammerOptions ):HammerManager;
  stop( force:boolean ):void;
}

declare class HammerInput
{
  constructor( manager:HammerManager, callback:Function );

  destroy():void;
  handler():void;
  init():void;

  /** Name of the event. Like panstart. */
  type:string;

  /** Movement of the X axis. */
  deltaX:number;

  /** Movement of the Y axis. */
  deltaY:number;

  /** Total time in ms since the first input. */
  deltaTime:number;

  /** Distance moved. */
  distance:number;

  /** Angle moved. */
  angle:number;

  /** Velocity on the X axis, in px/ms. */
  velocityX:number;

  /** Velocity on the Y axis, in px/ms */
  velocityY:number;

  /** Highest velocityX/Y value. */
  velocity:number;

  /** Direction moved. Matches the DIRECTION constants. */
  direction:number;

  /** Direction moved from it's starting point. Matches the DIRECTION constants. */
  offsetDirection:number;

  /** Scaling that has been done when multi-touch. 1 on a single touch. */
  scale:number;

  /** Rotation that has been done when multi-touch. 0 on a single touch. */
  rotation:number;

  /** Center position for multi-touch, or just the single pointer. */
  center:HammerPoint;

  /** Source event object, type TouchEvent, MouseEvent or PointerEvent. */
  srcEvent:TouchEvent | MouseEvent | PointerEvent;

  /** Target that received the event. */
  target:HTMLElement;

  /** Primary pointer type, could be touch, mouse, pen or kinect. */
  pointerType:string;

  /** Event type, matches the INPUT constants. */
  eventType:number;

  /** true when the first input. */
  isFirst:boolean;

  /** true when the final (last) input. */
  isFinal:boolean;

  /** Array with all pointers, including the ended pointers (touchend, mouseup). */
  pointers:any[];

  /** Array with all new/moved/lost pointers. */
  changedPointers:any[];

  /** Reference to the srcEvent.preventDefault() method. Only for experts! */
  preventDefault:Function;
}

declare class MouseInput extends HammerInput
{
  constructor( manager:HammerManager, callback:Function );
}

declare class PointerEventInput extends HammerInput
{
  constructor( manager:HammerManager, callback:Function );
}

declare class SingleTouchInput extends HammerInput
{
  constructor( manager:HammerManager, callback:Function );
}

declare class TouchInput extends HammerInput
{
  constructor( manager:HammerManager, callback:Function );
}

declare class TouchMouseInput extends HammerInput
{
  constructor( manager:HammerManager, callback:Function );
}

interface RecognizerOptions {
  direction?: number;
  enable?: boolean | ((recognizer: Recognizer, inputData: HammerInput) => boolean);
  event?: string;
  interval?: number;
  pointers?: number;
  posThreshold?: number;
  taps?: number
  threshold?: number;
  time?: number;
  velocity?: number;
}

interface RecognizerStatic
{
  new( options?:RecognizerOptions ):Recognizer;
}

interface Recognizer
{
  defaults:any;

  canEmit():boolean;
  canRecognizeWith( otherRecognizer:Recognizer ):boolean;
  dropRecognizeWith( otherRecognizer:Recognizer ):Recognizer;
  dropRecognizeWith( otherRecognizer:string ):Recognizer;
  dropRequireFailure( otherRecognizer:Recognizer ):Recognizer;
  dropRequireFailure( otherRecognizer:string ):Recognizer;
  emit( input:HammerInput ):void;
  getTouchAction():any[];
  hasRequireFailures():boolean;
  process( inputData:HammerInput ):string;
  recognize( inputData:HammerInput ):void;
  recognizeWith( otherRecognizer:Recognizer ):Recognizer;
  recognizeWith( otherRecognizer:string ):Recognizer;
  requireFailure( otherRecognizer:Recognizer ):Recognizer;
  requireFailure( otherRecognizer:string ):Recognizer;
  reset():void;
  set( options?:RecognizerOptions ):Recognizer;
  tryEmit( input:HammerInput ):void;
}

interface AttrRecognizerStatic
{
  attrTest( input:HammerInput ):boolean;
  process( input:HammerInput ):any;
}

interface AttrRecognizer extends Recognizer
{
  new( options?:RecognizerOptions ):AttrRecognizer;
}

interface PanRecognizerStatic
{
  new( options?:RecognizerOptions ):PanRecognizer;
}

interface PanRecognizer extends AttrRecognizer
{
}

interface PinchRecognizerStatic
{
  new( options?:RecognizerOptions ):PinchRecognizer;
}

interface PinchRecognizer extends AttrRecognizer
{
}

interface PressRecognizerStatic
{
  new( options?:RecognizerOptions ):PressRecognizer;
}

interface PressRecognizer extends AttrRecognizer
{
}

interface RotateRecognizerStatic
{
  new( options?:RecognizerOptions ):RotateRecognizer;
}

interface RotateRecognizer extends AttrRecognizer
{
}

interface SwipeRecognizerStatic
{
  new( options?:RecognizerOptions ):SwipeRecognizer;
}

interface SwipeRecognizer extends AttrRecognizer
{
}

interface TapRecognizerStatic
{
  new( options?:RecognizerOptions ):TapRecognizer;
}

interface TapRecognizer extends AttrRecognizer
{
}

declare class TouchAction
{
  constructor( manager:HammerManager, value:string );

  compute():string;
  preventDefaults( input:HammerInput ):void;
  preventSrc( srcEvent:any ):void;
  set( value:string ):void;
  update():void;
}

interface HammerPoint
{
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
```

Comment: This will help you understand and solve everything: http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/03/28/ambient-type-definitions-duplicate-identifier-typescript-fix/. You probably wont find better explanation from this one :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.